# DateTime parsing error: The supplied DateTime represents an invalid time

Tags: c#, datetime, timezone

I have one situation where date is `"3/13/2016 2:41:00 AM"`. When I convert date by time-zone, I get an error.

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse("3/13/2016 2:41:00 AM");
DateTime Date_Time = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeBySystemTimeZoneId(dt, "Eastern Standard Time", 
                                                                    "GMT Standard Time");
Response.Write(dt);
```

after execution, I get this error:

> The supplied DateTime represents an invalid time.  For example, when
>   the clock is adjusted forward, any time in the period that is skipped
>   is invalid. Parameter name: dateTime

Comment: It is **exactly** as the exception message describes.  March 13th was the day that EST moved from standard to daylight savings time.  There was no 2:41:00 AM, it was skipped when the clock moved instantly from 2 AM to 3 AM.  So the value you passed is just nonsense.  Garbage in, garbage out.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Exception calling when TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc for certain DateTime values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2416439/exception-calling-when-timezoneinfo-converttimetoutc-for-certain-datetime-values)

Comment: This is funny and never realized this until someone set a date in our system at 2am on 3/14/2021.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try to check if the time is ambiguous or a valid time. [Due to the daylight change](http://www.timeanddate.com/time/zone/usa/little-rock?syear=1990) the time you mentioned i.e, 2:41:00 AM doesn not exist since the clock was moved 1 hour ahead and hence the date is invalid or ambiguous.

```
2016    Sun, 13 Mar, 02:00  CST → CDT   +1 hour (DST start) UTC-5h
        Sun, 6 Nov, 02:00   CDT → CST   -1 hour (DST end)   UTC-6h
```

You can also refer to this blog: [System.TimeZoneInfo: Working with Ambiguous and Invalid Points in Time](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/bclteam/2007/06/11/system-timezoneinfo-working-with-ambiguous-and-invalid-points-in-time-josh-free/)

> System.TimeZoneInfo (currently available as part of .NET Framework 3.5
>   Beta 1) contains methods for checking if a DateTime instance
>   represents an ambiguous or invalid time in a specific time zone. These
>   methods are particularly useful for validating user-supplied points in
>   time.
>
> **Background Information**
>
> Time zones that adjust their time for Daylight Saving Time (in most
>   cases by moving the clock time back or forward by 1 hour) have gaps
>   and repeats in the timeline — wherever the clock time was moved
>   forward or back by the adjustment. Let’s use Pacific Standard Time as
>   an example. In 2007 Pacific Standard Time (PST) changes to Pacific
>   Daylight Time (PDT) at 02:00AM (“spring forward”) on the second Sunday
>   in March and then returns at 02:00AM (“fall back”) on the first Sunday
>   in November

To check if the time is valid you can use:

```
TimeZoneInfo.IsInvalidTime
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I was trying to convert a UTC date (thus, it was valid, as UTC dates don't skip any periods of time with DST).

The problem was that I was loading the date from Entity Framework and the `DateKind` was set to `Unspecified`. In that case, `ConvertTimeBySystemTimeZoneId` assumes it is a local time and may find it invalid.

The solution is to properly set the `DateKind` to `UTC` before converting:

```
var date = DateTime.ParseExact("2019-03-31T03:06:55.7856471", "O", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
// Here date.Kind == DateTimeKind.Unspecified

date = DateTime.SpecifyKind(date, DateTimeKind.Utc);
// Now date.Kind == DateTimeKind.Utc

// Now the conversion should work
TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeBySystemTimeZoneId(date, "Central Standard Time");
```