# C# DateTime not recognising timezone change (BST)

Tags: c#, datetime, dst

A few weeks ago, on 27th March 2016, the clocks in the UK went forward by one hour. At 01:00, the clocks 'jumped' forward to 02:00

http://www.timeanddate.com/time/dst/events.html

This means that "27 Mar 2016, 01:30", is an invalid datetime, i.e. it does not represent a time that actually 'happened'.

This recently caught us out when a Java date time parser was unable to understand the time we passed to it. However, the C# DateTime doesn't appear to have any problem with it at all.

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse("2016-03-27 01:30:00"); 
bool invalid = TimeZoneInfo.Local.IsInvalidTime(dt);
```

Although `invalid` is correctly set to `true`, `DateTime` doesn't appear to have any problem storing it.

Moreover, the following statement:

```
diff = new DateTime(2016, 3, 27, 2, 30, 0) - new DateTime(2016, 3, 27, 0, 30, 0);
```

results in a TimeSpan representing 2 hours, which is not correct.

Why does the DateTime type not account for DST?

Comment: As a fellow brit, I actually hadnt thought about this but as timezones around the world do their daylightsaving changes on different dates, Id almost be surprised if it would know..  Id expect it to only look at is the date/time valid eg between 00:00 and 23:59:59 and the date a valid date..

Comment: [NodaTime](http://nodatime.org/) probably fixes this for you. However, it has a different api.

Comment: See also [DateTime parsing error: The supplied DateTime represents an invalid time](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36422138/33499)

Comment: There is a reason why other APIs, like NodaTime, exists and the reason is that the built in types are woefully inadequate. Some support to fix this has been bolted on but it is not good enough. If you need to deal with timezones, use something else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, the only *question* here is:

> Why does the DateTime type not account for DST?

#### Short Answer

Because that's how the `DateTime` structure was designed.

From [the MSDN docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.aspx#datetime_ops):

> Conversion operations between time zones (such as between UTC and local time, or between one time zone and another) take daylight saving time into account, but arithmetic and comparison operations do not.

#### Longer Answer

.NET's `DateTime` only tracks two logical values, `Ticks` and `Kind`.  Internally, these are merged into a single 64-bit integer for performance and compatibility reasons, but you can think of them as two separate values.

- `Ticks` tracks the number of 100 nanosecond intervals since an epoch value of `0001-01-01 00:00:00`.
- `Kind` tracks metadata of whether the `Ticks` are intended to represent time in UTC, or in the computer's local time zone, or in some other unspecified time zone.

Every function that works with a `DateTime` is supposed to take `Kind` into consideration.  Many in the framework do.  Some do not.  Many other libraries, even some concerned with time, ignore it altogether.

When you called `DateTime.Parse("2016-03-27 01:30:00")`, the `Kind` is set to `Unspecified`, because there's no context. The value you provided isn't necessarily in any particular time zone, and thus neither is the `0001-01-01 00:00:00` epoch date.  In other words, you can think of it as just a date and a time that are not pinned to any offset from UTC or any DST rules.

Note this is considerably different from Java and JavaScript, where a `Date` object which tracks milliseconds since the `1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC` epoch.  It's *always* UTC, where .NET's may or may not be.

There are multiple ways to handle this.  The best by far is to use a more sensible API, which is offered by the [Noda Time](http://nodatime.org) open source library.  However, if you want to use only the functionality built in to .NET, then consider using the `DateTimeOffset` structure.  Unlike `DateTime`, it tracks its offset from UTC and takes it into account when doing math.

You will still have to check if the input is invalid with `TimeZoneInfo.IsInvalidTime`.  There is no API built in to .NET that will throw an exception for an invalid time when *parsing*.  You will, however, find that the conversion functions on `TimeZoneInfo`, such as `ConvertTimeToUtc` will indeed throw an exception if you pass in an invalid time for the source time zone.

You should also check `TimeZoneInfo.IsAmbiguousTime`, because given a value during the fall-back transition that occurs twice, such as `2016-10-30 01:30` for the UK, .NET will always pick the *standard* time offset.  While this may at first seem correct, consider that the *daylight* instance actually occurs first - which is usually the desired behavior in most real world scenarios (from my experiences anyway).

Aside, regarding your Java code, if you're not already you should consider using either [Joda Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) for Java 7 and lower, or [`java.time`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) that's built in to Java 8.  You'll find them very similar to [Noda Time](http://nodatime.org), mentioned earlier.

And lastly, I'll add my very opinionated assertion that the design of the `DateTime` structure violates [SRP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) in multiple ways.  In particular, `DateTimeKind` is an abomination - IMHO.

Comment: Lots of good answers here - thank you everyone. Matt has to get the mark for the most detail and for picking out the real question, which was really quite simple, if a little broad. Turns out DateTime isn't *quite* what I thought it was.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old but I came across it and thought others might be helped by this addition to the thread. Whilst the answer given by Matt Johnson-Pint is comprehensive and very helpful indeed, there is a simple method available to achieve the required 'tweak' to DateTime in order to show current local time - which I think answers the practical point:

```
    string dtNow = DateTime.Now.ToLocalTime().ToString();
```

In the UK BST this gives the correct result.

useful link [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tolocaltime?view=netframework-4.8)

Answer (score 0):

DateTime has a Kind property which indicates if it is Local time or UTC or Unspecified. Your parsing format doesn't allow it to set this Kind so it will be Unspecified. I think you need to set this to allow it correctly deal with DST.

Generally you deal with DateTimes in UTC format, and then convert to local DateTime when you need to display to the user to get around this issue.

Comment: Even setting the Kind property to local, it is still possible to have a DateTime representing 01:30 on that date. And the date diff part of my question still returns 2 hours.

Answer (score 0):

I guess Microsoft decided to supply you with the flexibility to manage the invalid dates yourself with the IsInvalidTime method.

If your application has a requirement for the date to be valid then you should be checking if the time is valid.

Answer (score 0):

Azure Web Apps have a nice default setting that can be used to change this either in the Azure interface or Visual Studio.
There is a great blog here that shows you how to do it:
https://www.jasongaylord.com/blog/tip-changing-an-azure-app-service-time-zone